# Building LLVM for IPU

Tags: llvm, ipu

I'm trying to install [LLVM for IPU](https://github.com/graphcore/llvm-project-fork).

I tried to build as it is usually done for the chosen architecture

```
cmake -S llvm -B build -G Ninja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install_llvm/ -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="Colossus" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
cmake --build build -j 16
```

But the process crashes with the following error

```
ninja: error: 'lib/Target/Colossus/ISDOpcodeConstantsPrinter/clang', needed by 'isd_opcode_constants.ll', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Can you share the installation guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LLVM build for the IPU backend has a requirement for the subproject Clang to be built. To fix your error, enable the clang project as so: `-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=";clang;lld"`

We have dedicated a community slack channel available if you need any further support.

https://app.slack.com/client/T039718RC3F/C03EYU38LM9